# How to Create a Stage Channel on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Yes, I know this is a new feature and might not get an answer.

Today, discord made a new feature called 'Stage Channels' pretty neat and awesome and I would like to code a discord.py bot to create a discord channel. This is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

prefix = "r!"
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('connected to Discord as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.command()
async def livechannel(ctx):
  await ctx.guild.create_role(name="Role Name")
  await ctx.guild.create_stage_channel('Stage Name')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

it works fine if I change stage to tex and it creates the role.

Comment: If discord added the new stage channels feature today it's obvious discord.py will not support them right out of the gate, you have to wait till there's a new version released and hopefully they will be supported

Comment: Ok well, that's what I thought. I also found that ur bot needs a dev license ($25) to make announcement channels, so it probably will need that for stage channels aswell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.7 has just been released to PyPi, and it comes with stage channels support, to create a stage channel:

```py
await guild.create_stage_channel(...)
```

#### Reference:

- [`Guild.create_stage_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_stage_channel)

Comment: Yes, this worked, thank you! Just note you MUST type `pip install --upgrade discord.py`, thanks :D now how do u close this...

Answer (score 3):

discord.py doesn't already support them. You don't have any feature for now. The only way is to use the discord api with the requests module, give a look at the official discord.com/developers docs. I see them, and currently they are not documented. Wait at least a eek to see them appear on the docs, and at least one month to see the feature work on discord.py!

Comment: Ok, yesterday discord.py 1.7 was released and you are now able to create stage channels. Check out their docs. Happy coding! I took this feature required longest time to discord.py team, but I mistook.

Comment: You removed the content for which you got upvotes. Please phrase your update differently so as to preserve the content, "see above is not an answer". If you decide that the post is or becamse meaningless you can delete it (and get a badge for it).